# How to drag and rotate user control in canvas layout

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, rotation, drag

I'm developing an application where I have to drag a user control on a canvas. 
This user control can be dragged in normal position or rotated with an angle of 90, 180, 270 degree. 
I have a problem when dragging the user control with an angle of 90 or 270 degrees because the user control is shifted to the drop point at mouse release. 
I have tried with `TransformToVisual` method of the control, but it doesn't work fine. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?
If you need of some code or file asked me. 
Thanks.

Edit:

this is my ProdottoCtrl code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Libreria_Controlli
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Logica di interazione per ProdottoCtrl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProdottoCtrl : ProdottoCtrlBase
    {
        Rect _rectCanvasDrop1;
        Rect _rectCanvasDrop2;

        bool _isFuoriConfineDrop1;
        bool _isFuoriConfineDrop2;
        bool _isContatto = false;

        public ProdottoCtrl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region Proprietà User Control

        #region CanvasDrag
        public Canvas CanvasDrag
        {
            get { return (Canvas)GetValue(CanvasDragProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CanvasDragProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CanvasDrag.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasDragProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasDrag", typeof(Canvas), typeof(ProdottoCtrl));
        #endregion

        #region CanvasDrop1

        public CanvasDropCtrl CanvasDrop1
        {
            get { return (CanvasDropCtrl)GetValue(CanvasDrop1Property); }
            set { SetValue(CanvasDrop1Property, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CanvasDrop1.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasDrop1Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasDrop1", typeof(CanvasDropCtrl), typeof(ProdottoCtrl));

        #endregion

        #region CanvasDrop2
        public CanvasDropCtrl CanvasDrop2
        {
            get { return (CanvasDropCtrl)GetValue(CanvasDrop2Property); }
            set { SetValue(CanvasDrop2Property, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CanvasDrop2.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasDrop2Property =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasDrop2", typeof(CanvasDropCtrl), typeof(ProdottoCtrl));
        #endregion

        #endregion

        #region Drag handlers
        private void RettangoloProdotto_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _posizioneMouseIniziale= e.GetPosition(TopWindow);

            // DA MUOVERE
            _rectCanvasDrop1 = CanvasDrop1.Canvas.TransformToVisual(TopWindow).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, CanvasDrop1.ActualWidth, CanvasDrop1.ActualHeight));
            _rectCanvasDrop2 = CanvasDrop2.Canvas.TransformToVisual(TopWindow).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, CanvasDrop2.ActualWidth, CanvasDrop2.ActualHeight));

            _isDrag = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void RettangoloProdotto_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(_isDrag)
            {
                if(IsMinimaDistanzaDrag(e.GetPosition(TopWindow)))
                {
                    if(_rettangoloOutline == null)
                    {

                        _rettangoloOutline = new Rectangle();
                        _rettangoloOutline.Width = RettangoloProdotto.Width;
                        _rettangoloOutline.Height = RettangoloProdotto.Height;
                        _rettangoloOutline.Fill = RettangoloProdotto.Fill;
                        _rettangoloOutline.RenderTransform = GridMain.RenderTransform;
                        _rettangoloOutline.Opacity = 0.8;


                        CanvasDrag.Children.Add(_rettangoloOutline);

                        TopWindow.MouseLeftButtonUp += TopWindow_MouseLeftButtonUp;
                        TopWindow.MouseMove += TopWindow_MouseMove;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void TopWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_isDrag || _rettangoloOutline == null)
                return;

            #region Offset rotazione            
            if (Rotazione == 0)
            {
                delta.X = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrag).X - _rectOutline.Width / 2;
                delta.Y = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrag).Y - _rectOutline.Height / 2;
            }
            else if (Rotazione == 90)
            {
                delta.X = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrag).X + _rectOutline.Width / 2;
                delta.Y = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrag).Y - _rectOutline.Height / 2;
            }
            else if (Rotazione == 180)
            {
                delta.X = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrag).X + _rectOutline.Width / 2;
                delta.Y = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrag).Y + _rectOutline.Height / 2;
            }
            else if (Rotazione == 270)
            {
                delta.X = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrag).X - _rectOutline.Width / 2;
                delta.Y = e.GetPosition(CanvasDrag).Y + _rectOutline.Height / 2;
            } 
            #endregion

            Canvas.SetLeft(_rettangoloOutline, delta.X);
            Canvas.SetTop(_rettangoloOutline, delta.Y);

            _rectOutline = _rettangoloOutline.TransformToVisual(TopWindow).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, _rettangoloOutline.Width, _rettangoloOutline.Height));

            _isFuoriConfineDrop1 = IsFuoriConfine(_rectCanvasDrop1);
            _isFuoriConfineDrop2 = IsFuoriConfine(_rectCanvasDrop2);
            _isContatto = IsContatto(); // VErificare velocità con molti pacchi

            if (_isFuoriConfineDrop1)
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.No;
            else
                Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        }

        private void TopWindow_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            e.Handled = true;

            if (!_isDrag)
                return;           

            TopWindow.MouseLeftButtonUp -= TopWindow_MouseLeftButtonUp;
            TopWindow.MouseMove -= TopWindow_MouseMove;

            // Il prodotto è fuori dai confini, avverto l'utente
            if (_isFuoriConfineDrop1 && _isFuoriConfineDrop2)
            {
                // Avverto  l'utente con un avviso visuale (messageBox o meglio segnali sullo
                // User control
            }
            else if(!_isFuoriConfineDrop1) // Sono nel primo CanvasDrop
            {
                if(_isContatto)
                {
                    // Avverto utente del contatto

                }
                else
                {

                    Point p = _rettangoloOutline.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), CanvasDrop1.Canvas);

                    ProdottoDropCtrl prodottoDrop = CreaProdottoDrop();
                    CanvasDrop1.Canvas.Children.Add(prodottoDrop);

                    Point pointSnap = SnapToGrid(new Point(p.X, p.Y));
                    Canvas.SetLeft(prodottoDrop, pointSnap.X );
                    Canvas.SetTop(prodottoDrop, pointSnap.Y);
                }
            }


            if (_rettangoloOutline != null)
            {
                CanvasDrag.Children.Remove(_rettangoloOutline);
                _rettangoloOutline = null;
            }
            _isDrag = false;

            Console.WriteLine("pallet1_Interno {0} - pallet2_Interno {1} - Contatto {2}", !_isFuoriConfineDrop1, !_isFuoriConfineDrop2, _isContatto);            

        }
        #endregion

        private bool IsContatto()
        {
            CanvasDropCtrl canvasDrop = null;

            if (_isFuoriConfineDrop1 && _isFuoriConfineDrop2)
                return false;

            // Sono nel primo pallet
            if (_isFuoriConfineDrop2)
                canvasDrop = CanvasDrop1;
            else // Sono nel secondo pallet
                canvasDrop = CanvasDrop2;

            foreach(var prodotto in canvasDrop.Canvas.Children)
            {
                ProdottoCtrlBase prodottoDrop = prodotto as ProdottoCtrlBase;

                if (this.Equals(prodottoDrop) || prodottoDrop == null)
                    continue;

                Rect rectProdottoDrop = prodottoDrop.TransformToVisual(TopWindow).TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, prodottoDrop.Lunghezza, prodottoDrop.Profondita));

                // Contatto - UPDATE: contatto in un solo punto ???
                if (rectProdottoDrop.IntersectsWith(_rectOutline))
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        private ProdottoDropCtrl CreaProdottoDrop()
        {
            ProdottoDropCtrl prodottoDrop = new ProdottoDropCtrl();
            prodottoDrop.Altezza = Altezza;
            prodottoDrop.Lunghezza = Lunghezza;
            prodottoDrop.Profondita = Profondita;
            prodottoDrop.Rotazione = Rotazione;
            prodottoDrop.GridSize = GridSize;

            prodottoDrop.TopWindow = TopWindow;
            if (!_isFuoriConfineDrop1)
            {
                prodottoDrop.CanvasDrop = CanvasDrop1;
                prodottoDrop.NumeroProdotto = NumeroProdottiCanvas(CanvasDrop1) + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                prodottoDrop.CanvasDrop = CanvasDrop2;
                prodottoDrop.NumeroProdotto = NumeroProdottiCanvas(CanvasDrop2) + 1;
            }            

            return prodottoDrop;
        }

        private int NumeroProdottiCanvas(CanvasDropCtrl canvasDrop)
        {
            int numeroProdotti = 0;

            foreach (var item in canvasDrop.Canvas.Children)
            {
                if (item is ProdottoDropCtrl)
                    numeroProdotti++;
            }

            return numeroProdotti;

        }
    }
}
```

ProdottoCtrl.xaml:

```
<local:ProdottoCtrlBase x:Class="Libreria_Controlli.ProdottoCtrl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Libreria_Controlli"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             x:Name="UsrCtrl"
             Height="{Binding ElementName=UsrCtrl, Path=Profondita}"
             Width="{Binding ElementName=UsrCtrl, Path=Lunghezza}"
             Focusable="True" >

    <Grid Name="GridMain" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
          Height="{Binding ElementName=UsrCtrl, Path=Profondita}"
          Width="{Binding ElementName=UsrCtrl, Path=Lunghezza}">

        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ElementName=UsrCtrl, Path=Rotazione}" />
        </Grid.RenderTransform>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Name="RettangoloEtichetta" Margin="5,0" Width="50" Height="5" Fill="White" Panel.ZIndex="100" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

        <Rectangle Name="RettangoloProdotto"
                   Height="{Binding ElementName=UsrCtrl, Path=Profondita}"
                   Width="{Binding ElementName=UsrCtrl, Path=Lunghezza}"
                   Fill="Coral"
                   Grid.RowSpan="2"

                   MouseLeftButtonDown="RettangoloProdotto_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                   MouseMove="RettangoloProdotto_MouseMove"/>

    </Grid>

</local:ProdottoCtrlBase>
```

Comment: Could you provde code for : rotate,move, user control class

Comment: nobody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the centerX and centerY values of the RotateTransform to the rotated elements half width and half height. This way you can drag the object relative to its position in its parent as if you would do if it was not rotated.

Example:

```
if(rotateTransform != null)
  { RotateTransform t = RotateTransform(rotateTransform.Angle + <rotationValue>, Width/2, Height/2);
    RenderTransform = t;
  }
```

In your MouseMove-Handler you do not need to adapt the movement:

```
    private void handleMouseMoveEvent(object sender, MouseEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            Point parentPosition = Mouse.GetPosition(parentCanvas);   

            Canvas.SetLeft(this, (parentPosition.X - Width / 2));
            Canvas.SetTop(this, (parentPosition.Y - Height / 2));                
        }

        args.Handled = true;

     }
```

Hope this helps!

Cheers,

Alex